# How to pass a stored procedure value into an XML and store it in the XML variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a requirement where I have a stored procedure in my database. I have an XML file from which I'm fetching the values from the stored procedure using query.

```
<dataSource connector="sqlserver" name="Sales">
    <query>
        StoredProcedureName '2016', 14, -1, 0, 0, -1
    </query>
</dataSource>`
```

which returns 201565. Now I want to store that value into a variable and use it as an attribute in the same XML document.

EX: I have

```
<yAxises>
    <yAxis min="0" max="100">
        <labels step="2"></labels>
```

in the place of 100, I want to pass the returned value i.e., 201565. Is it possible to do in XML? Please help me on it.

Comment: As far as I understand the upper part is rather irrelevant. You read a SP's name and parameters and you get a value back. The rest is not fully clear... Is the `<yAxis>`-node already part of the original XML? Is the `<dataSource>`-example the target XML and is it complete? Where do you want to insert this? Where do the other values come from? Please edit your question and provide the target XML before and after your operation.

Comment: This question appears to be about some kind of tool external to SQL Server (based on the `<dataSource>` and `<query>` tags ) - maybe an ETL tool or an ORM of some description, but there isn't enough info here to figure out which one!